# Using chrome.runtime.sendMessage to pass objects which have functions

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

As CORS have been blocked in chrome V76, I am trying to move them from content script to background page in my chrome extension. This includes several API calls.

After referring to this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814553/sending-object-with-functions-via-chrome-runtime-sendmessage), I have the following code -

**`Content script`**

```
var translatorj = JSON.stringify(translator, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value.toString();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({contentScriptQuery: 'getTranslations2', translator: translatorj, cwNotMatch: cwNotMatch}, tMap => {
  this.processTranslations(tMap, this.userDefinedTranslations, cwMatch);
});
```

**`Background page`**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.contentScriptQuery === 'getTranslations2') {
    var translatorj = JSON.parse(request.translator);
    translatorj.getTranslations(request.cwNoMatch)
      .then(tMap => sendResponse(tMap))
      .catch(e => {
        console.error('[MTW]', e);
      });
    return true;
  }
```

This however doesn't work, how should I go about sending the object?

Comment: Since the data must be JSON-compatible, you can't pass functions. Passing their stringified code isn't helpful either. Anyway, there should be no need for that: simply load the relevant script in the "background" section of manifest.json and use it with the passed data.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the suggestion, I will try to implement it.